# GLOB_BRACE portability?

Tags: php, unix, gnu, glob

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534455/regular-expression-to-match-unlimited-number-of-options), I was made aware of glob()'s `GLOB_BRACE` option that allows for a limited set of regular expressions when searching for files.

This looks just like what I need, but according to the [manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), `GLOB_BRACE` is "not available on some Non-GNU Operating systems." Among those seems to be Solaris.

I am building an application that is supposed to be as portable as possible, so I need to check out possible problems as early as possible.

Does somebody know of other platforms apart from Solaris where `GLOB_BRACE` is not supported? How about Mac OS >= X for example? It's built on top of a Unix. Is every Unix automatically a "GNU" platform as defined in the manual?

Comment: Greetings from the future: Alpine Linux does not support this. PHP is aware. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72095

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the relevant [`glob(3)` man page](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/glob.3.html) for the *nix variant will tell you whether or not it supports `GLOB_BRACE`.

Comment: Cheers @Ignacio, that is good to know. Seeing as it's supported on OS X, presumably any Linux, and Windows, I think I can go ahead with this.